# Javascript - How to loop print html paragraph with id and class

Tags: javascript

I want to print the paragraph element so that it includes the id number from 1 through 100. I want javascript to have to print them instead of writing them manually.

HTML code:

```
      <div id="shields">
       <p class="houses" id="1">HOUSE 1</p>
       <p class="houses" id="2">HOUSE 2</p>
       <p class="houses" id="3">HOUSE 3</p>
       <p class="houses" id="5">HOUSE 4</p>
       <p class="houses" id="6">HOUSE 5</p>
       <p class="houses" id="7">HOUSE 6</p>
       <p class="houses" id="4">HOUSE 7</p>
       <p class="houses" id="8">HOUSE 8</p>
       <p class="houses" id="9">HOUSE 9</p>
       <p class="houses" id="10">HOUSE 10</p>
      </div>
```

Something like this where House 1 has the id number of 1.
[image: House print]

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript for loop to achieve this like the following

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  let ptag = document.createElement('p');
  ptag.classList.add('houses');
  ptag.id = i;
  ptag.innerHTML = `HOUSE ${i}`;
  document.getElementById('shields').appendChild(ptag);
}
```

```html
<div id="shields">
</div>
```

Comment: This seemed to work. Thanks, Vishnu!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to loop from `1` to `100` and append the HTML dynamically to the `div`:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  shields.innerHTML += `<p class="houses" id="${i}">HOUSE ${i}</p>`;
}
```

```html
<div id="shields"></div>
```